# Bulk image format conversion from from .bmp to .jpg via command line?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, batch

My screen capture program saves .bmp images, which are not usable in Google Docs, which will accept .jpg

Is there a clever way to create a set of .jpg from the .bmp files via the command line?  Bonus for use of a command that is native to Ubuntu install.  If not, please communicate line of reasoning for selecting software.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Than use imagemagick's tool mogrify:

```
mogrify -format jpg /path/to/your/bmps/*.bmp
```

Why? 'cause it works.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the amplifying edit, Muru. But I must insist on the right word. "Imagemicks" is a plural noun referring to Irish photographers. It's not PC. ;-)